# Compare two asynchronous values while using Angularfire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

How can two values be compared?

```
<span *ngIf="(event | async)?.date !== (event | async)?.endDate">
  {{ (event | async)?.endDate }}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subscribing too many times, I'd try to refactor like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="event | async as e">
    <span *ngIf="e.date !== e.endDate">
        {{ e.endDate }}
      </span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you. So should I wrap the entire html which uses event data in an `ng-container`?

Comment: There's no one solution fits all, For the use case in question, this should work, as all the values you are trying to compare are in the same object. ng-container is in general a nice construct that adds no html to template and to be used for situations like this.